# Ошибка Duplicate class

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Я новичок в Android Stidio и Java в целом.

Написав небольшой парсер для Mp3 я начал получать следующую ошибку вообще во всех моих проектах

```
Duplicate class org.w3c.dom.DOMConfiguration found in modules jetified-xml-apis-1.3.03.jar (xml-apis:xml-apis:1.3.03) and jetified-xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar (org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:2.3.0)
Duplicate class org.w3c.dom.DOMStringList found in modules jetified-xml-apis-1.3.03.jar (xml-apis:xml-apis:1.3.03) and jetified-xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar (org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:2.3.0)
Duplicate class org.w3c.dom.TypeInfo found in modules jetified-xml-apis-1.3.03.jar (xml-apis:xml-apis:1.3.03) and jetified-xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar (org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:2.3.0)
Duplicate class org.w3c.dom.UserDataHandler found in modules jetified-xml-apis-1.3.03.jar (xml-apis:xml-apis:1.3.03) and jetified-xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar (org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:2.3.0)
```

Как это исправить, это не должно быть сложно, но я не понимаю как это сделать.

Comment: Возможно какой-то баг в кэша системы сборки. Попробуйте `Invalidate cache and restart` в основном меню IDE выполнить.

Comment: С ошибкой в других проектах мне удалось разобраться, а вот парсер продолжает выдавать подобное, хотя я не понимаю когда я успел создать дублированный класс

Comment: Судя по тексту у вас в двух разных либах один и тот же класс. Попробуйте одну из либ убрать.

Comment: implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation group: 'org.apache.tika', name: 'tika-parsers', version: '1.4'

    implementation group: 'org.apache.tika', name: 'tika-core', version: '1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'  я подключаю лишь эти библиотеки, оне не должны конфликтовать

Comment: Почему вы думаете, что они не должны конфликтовать? Попробуйте убрать те, которые с `group: 'org.apache.tika'`

Comment: И в комменты такое лучше не писать - нечитаемо получается. Лучше добавлять в сам вопрос, через правку оного.